# Java help ArrayList of ArrayList not unique

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a small bit of code that is only semi functional. can someone explain to me why my ArrayList> ALL_PIXELS is holding the same value for every location?

//why is this not making ALL_PIXELS unique for each row .............

```
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_HEIGHT; i++) {

        HashMap<String, Double> t = boundsHistory.get(zoomNum);
        PI task = new PI(i, t);
        //this is the problem. some where 
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        temp = task.execute();
        //System.out.println(temp);
        ALL_PIXELS.add(temp);
        //System.out.println(ALL_PIXELS.get(i));     //still unique here....WHYYYYYYY
        //System.out.println(temp);     //this shows that temp is a unique array each row

    }// end for loop    



    //why is all pixels seting the same vales to all of its sub arrays
    //System.out.println(ALL_PIXELS.get(3));
    //System.out.println(ALL_PIXELS.get(300));
```

Any advice would be nice on how to make sure the ALL_PIXELS array list stay unique when i print it off after the for loop.

Comment: What does `task.execute()` return and what do you mean with *"same value for every location"*? Btw you can also write `ALL_PIXELS.add(task.execute());`, because `temp` holds nothing else then the returned value of `task.execute()`.

Comment: This line `ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>()` is useless since you're overwriting `temp` on the next line `temp = task.execute()`.

Comment: You haven't presented enough code to answer the question.  The implementation of `PI.execute()` would seem to be the most important missing piece.

Comment: It's a little bit strange that you retrieve `boundsHistory.get(zoomNum)` on every loop iteration, when there's no evidence that the result will change from iteration to iteration.  It's not inherently wrong (especially if the result *could* change), but if you can rely on the result not to change then it would be better to lift that out of the loop.

Comment: here is a better representation of my problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976612/java-arraylist-of-arraylist-of-integers-not-working-right

the code was to much to fit in here